# how to make COM connection point a pure Asynchronous communication

Tags: winapi, com

I have wrote one sample com server which implements com connection point. I am calling one method in this COM object which in turn calling some other method in my client code using connection point mechanism.

But all the above listed operation is synchronous communication. I would like to make COM server pure async so that if my COM server get some event it should fire the data back to its client.

please suggest how it is possible using COM connection point.

Note :- My COM server is running as a exe out of proc.

Thanks in advance!!!

Regards
Ashish

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Same as you do it without COM:

1. the client of your server object calls a method;
2. the method starts a background operation and returns;
3. The background operation can use a separate thread, an async I/O API, a timer API, etc. When the background operation has completed, it fires an event (calls a method on the client-provided sink interface);
4. the client handles the event.

Back to COM, all method invocations in COM are synchronous by default. When you fire an event on the client-provided sink interface, the call will block until the client returns. There's one exception to this behavior: [`IAdviseSink`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms692513%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). The methods of this interface are asynchronous, if the callee resides in a different COM apartment from the caller. However, `IAdviseSink` is probably not what you're looking for.

Comment: Thanks for your answer....Actually I have to fire client method back  from the same method of COM which I have called from my client.

Comment: @user2893899, no problem, but it's *not* going to be asynchronous if your fire the event while the client is still calling out the server's method. Watch out for re-entrancy.

Answer (score 3):

Threading is *never* a minor detail in COM, just as it isn't in any runtime environment.  You **must** observe the apartment state that the COM client program selected.  And if it is STA, by far the most common selection, then it is your duty to fire the event on the thread that the client code selected.  Ignoring that requirement just produces impossible to diagnose bugs in the client program.

So if you fire the event from a worker thread in your own code, the only way to get event handlers to run async, then you **must** marshal the interface pointer.  CoMarshalThreadInterfaceInStream() or the easier-to-use IGlobalInterfaceTable gets that job done.  Rock-hard requirement.  It will run asynchronously when the client program opted-in by using COINIT_MULTITHREADED when it called CoInitializeEx().  The only thing you can do is publish the fact that *your* code is thread-safe by picking the ThreadingModel registry value, using "Both" or "Free".

Answer (score 1):

The standard way to use [asynchronous COM](http://www.microsoft.com/msj/0599/com/com0599.aspx) requires that the interface have an separate UUID for the asynchronous interface.  [`IConnectionPoint`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms694318%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) does not have an async UUID, so you can't use [`ICallFactory`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms680133%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) to implement asynchronous COM.